# Office Add-in Dialog box Cannot GET /popup.html

Tags: reactjs, office-js, office-addins

I am trying to add a Dialog Box in an Office Add-in using the Dialog API. I am using React for this add-in. I am able to open the dialog box but I get the error `Cannot GET /popup.html` when the dialog box opens.

When I run the application and go to my browser I can access the `taskpane.html` with the link https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html. But when I try to access `popup.html` in the same way I get the error  `Cannot GET /popup.html`.

My question is do I have to add something to the manifest.xml or something else in the code to allow this `popup.html` to be accessible? My `popup.html` is in the same directory as the `taskpane.html`.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Since the problem happens in the browser, this isn't really an issue with office.js or office-addins. Nothing in the manifest is going to fix it. I think you should retag this question to attract attention from general web app developers.

Comment: @RickKirkham The issue happens in Word as well, I was just using the browser as another way to test the issue.

Comment: Yes. I understand, but the fact that it happens in a browser means that the problem has no connection to the fact that the web app is a Word add-in. If it did, then the problem would _only_ happen in Word. There's something wrong with the web application _as a web application_, not _as a Word add-in_.

Comment: Sure, my thinking is that since this error would be common to those setting up a dialog box and would have more insight than if the post was general to the react community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the html file that I had to look in /src/taskpane/popup.html.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem happen to me (down to the same filename and path). What you need to do is modify  the `webpack.config.js` file on the root of your add-in folder and add this under `module.exports` > `plugins`:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: "popup.html",
  template: "./src/popup/popup.html",
  chunks: ["polyfill", "popup"]
})
```